# Cannot switch view in HTML5 mode in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am playing around with [this code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm) to make it work with HTML5 links. Somehow I am not able to make it work: the view is not resolved into URL. In addition, I am not clear whether I need to put "/" in front of a view name. If I do, the browser URL link shows **"file:///addStudent"** without any base, on the other hand , if I do not, I see the URL with base. Is it supposed to be like that? In any case I see error message: **"This webpage is not found"**. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

testAngularJS.htm

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Angular JS Views</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <base href="file:///home/myusername/projects/parser_ui/">
</head>
<body>
   <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
   <div ng-app="mainApp">
      <p><a href="addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
      <p><a href="viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
      <div ng-view></div>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="addStudent.htm">
         <h2> Add Student </h2>
         {{message}}
      </script>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="viewStudents.htm">
         <h2> View Students </h2>       
         {{message}}
      </script> 
   </div>

   <script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

      mainApp.config["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            // use the HTML5 History API
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider.
               when('/addStudent', {
                  templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
                  controller: 'AddStudentController'
               }).
               when('/viewStudents', {
                  templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
                  controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
               }).
               otherwise({
                  redirectTo: 'addStudent'
               });
      }];

      mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
         $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
      });

      mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
         $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `templateUrl` properties should **not** be prefixed with a `/`. When using the template cache (as you are with those `<script type="text/ng-template">` tags), the requested template must match the `id` **exactly**

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Please update your question with any changes

Comment: Ah, I'd also remove the `/` prefix from your `<a>` `href` attributes. The `<base>` tag takes care of where relative URIs are based from

Comment: Just did copy-paste of the whole code with changes again.

Comment: removed / prefix from your <a> href  too.

Comment: @Phil gave you the answer

Comment: @Incognos: I did all the changes, however, it did not resolve the issues so far.

Comment: @Incognos no, I didn't. OP, you'll probably have better success not running it from `file:///`

Comment: @phil he is right, I added a plunker and it behaves as he says: http://plnkr.co/edit/gWH3tkx5sJunNthwGAmK?p=preview

Comment: You main app.config is missing parens

Comment: @Incgnos: BTW, the original code with non-HTML5 links works.

Comment: @Incognos aha! Great catch. Man that was hard to spot

Comment: @Phil: Why do you think that "file:///" might be the issue? I am fairly new to it and I did not want to also dive into server installation like node.js.

Comment: The injectables are also in the wrong order

Comment: @Incognos: seems like you see the issue. What parens is missing and where? I am still puzzled. thanks.

Comment: before the '[' and after 'config' - then at the end after the ']' - but does not seem to solve the issue on plunker, even when putting injectables in right order

Comment: This is not the issue, you can do config like that. In fact it is the workaround you need to use, otherwise $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); throws an error which is AngularJS bug.

Comment: @Incognos your plunker doesn't work because of your `<base>` tag. I'm getting an error locally due to `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` ~ *"Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"*

Comment: removed `<base>` tag - now getting 404

Comment: @Phil, this is probably because you added parens. This is angular bug, see my previous comment.

Comment: @jazzblue  more than likely it's an issue to do with attempting to manipulate `location` / `history` and using a `file:///` protocol. It might even be a browser setting you need to enable

Comment: @Phil understood. However, as I said earlier, I tried the original example which does not use HTML5  mode and it works. I tend to think (although I might be wrong) that since file:/// worked with non-HTML5 mode, why would it fail with HTML5 mode?

Comment: @Phil In any case, if I am to get rid of file:///, should I use nodejs? Is there any easier way, so that I would not be stuck with setting up the server and learning it?

Comment: @jazzblue  Node's Express is very easy to use. You can even check out the angular-seed project on Github which comes all ready to run

Comment: @Phil: I have tried with nodejs express and get the same issue. I wonder, do you happen to know any working example that uses views with HTML5 mode that you can point me to? Thanks!

Comment: Got it to run with nodejs and express in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Runs in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gWH3tkx5sJunNthwGAmK?p=preview) but not locally here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Angular JS Views</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
   <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
   <div ng-app="mainApp">
      <p><a href="/addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
      <p><a href="/viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
      <div ng-view></div>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="addStudent.htm">
         <h2> Add Student </h2>
         {{message}}
      </script>
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="viewStudents.htm">
         <h2> View Students </h2>       
         {{message}}
      </script> 
   </div>
   <script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);

      mainApp.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

            // use the HTML5 History API
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider.
               when('/addStudent', {
                  templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
                  controller: 'AddStudentController'
               }).
               when('/viewStudents', {
                  templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
                  controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
               }).
               otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/addStudent'
               });
      }]);

      mainApp.controller('AddStudentController', function($scope) {
         $scope.message = "This page will be used to display add student form";
      });

      mainApp.controller('ViewStudentsController', function($scope) {
         $scope.message = "This page will be used to display all the students";
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use HTML5 mode without a `<base>` tag

Comment: added, but with an href of '/'

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was able to make it work in the end. So here is 
 what needs to be done:

1. Has to be run on server, not local file *(file:///)*. I used nodejs with Express suggested by Phil in the comments above.
2. In this line (below) I removed parenthesis since with using *file:///* it gave me an error. I did it due to some other recommendation on SO. However, the parenthesis must be there, otherwise, it will not work with the server.

   ```
   mainApp.config["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   ```

...should be:

```
   mainApp.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

3. Since AngularJS is a SPA framework, you might also find that you need to configure your server to pass all the URLs to Angular, so that all the */* would be interpreted as a view and not a folder/file.

For instance, in nodejs I added the following:

```
app.use('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/angular/views/index.html'));
});
```

having said that, when I commented the above out, it still worked fine and I am not sure why.